# Is there a way i can set the Edit text to leave a text box on pressing the "Enter" key?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinput

I have created an edit text box where the user can input information. As soon as the user clicks on the box the text keys of the android phone comes up. However, when the user finishes entering information and presses the "Enter" key, the text box is wiped clean and the user has to re-enter the information. Is there a way i can set the Edit text to leave the text box on pressing enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_edit_text.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
       // do your stuff here
         return true;
    }
});
```